# Select Nth rows for Chart Data Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to generate a chart in Google Sheets that will show data for specific days in a week (a chart for Monday, Tuesday, etc.) I have sequential dates running in a single column down the rows and I am able to chart the other data associated with these dates from the other columns, however, I can't seem to select the data for every Nth row, only for all rows.

The only solution I could come up with is manually adding a new Series for every instance, but this isn't a viable solution.

To simplify, I have a chart showing trends throughout the entirety of my dataset, but I'd like to have charts for days of the week as well (SUN - SAT). Is there a way to do this inside of Google Sheets, or is there an external tool that will be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Its very possible.

It would be easier if you could share a sample sheet with some data.

This is the basic idea, say your Dates are in A and your data is in B.  This formula:

`=FILTER(A2:B,WEEKDAY(A2:A)=1)` would show ONLY sunday data, `=FILTER(A2:B,WEEKDAY(A2:A)=2)` would show ONLY monday data,

etc.

Comment: Here is a copy of the data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fvc4ecuu0MRvbfzu80zGSFRerlxklQGvcL6wR21_0GM/edit?usp=sharing

The issue is that when you edit a Chart, you can only select a data range, and you are not able to use a formula.

Upon further consideration, I think I could just create new columns that provide the sorted data but is this truly the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the charts to grab data continuously as you add data to the sheet.

I think it's time to introduce you to Google Charts API.
There are two approaches I can foresee of the top of my head:

1. Use an Apps Script to build your chart with the [Charts service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts) and the [Spreadsheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) and embed it into the spreadsheet.

OR

2. Deploy the script as a [a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and build a charts dashboard using the [Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start)

Either way you can harness all the power of Apps script.

**Further reading:**

- [How to use Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs)
- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)